# How the stdin, stdout, stderr are closed

Tags: java, c++, c, io, operating-system

In most modern programming languages, programmers don't need to *close* the `stdin`,`stdout`,`stderr`. Does it mean that the operating system will handle the close of the `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` in general?

Or for instance in `java`, the `jvm` will close the `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` when the running Java program `exit`?

There might be exceptions like some old programmers mentioned, so hereby I narrow down the language spectrum to Java, C, C++ only

Comment: too broad, maybe you better pick one OS and one language

Comment: The C++ library will flush anything that these streams have buffered up, before the program normally terminates. The process inherits the underlying files, so there's nothing to close, but, technically, the operating system will release all resources used by the process when it terminates.

Comment: @user463035818 I bet this does not depend on a single language or OS

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  I agree with yours :) But would be better to get more authorized answer

Comment: I'm sure that, at least, the part about the C++ library flushing the output streams is buried somewhere in the 1400+ pages that make up the current C++ standard. But this is such a minor detail, that, perhaps, if you explain the actual reason why you need an "authorized answer", then someone might be motivated enough to look it up.

Comment: See point (2) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit

Comment: @Rui Well `C` and `C++` are different from many languages in this in that, in special circumstances the programmer can close them directly, rather than letting the parent process do it. I don't know of another language that allows for this but there probably are.

Comment: You should study other languages, like LISP,BASIC, Pascal and Fortran which don't have `stdin`, `stdout` or `stderr`.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all programs run under a C run-time, so upon normal termination the rules of the C `exit()` function should apply. Per **7.22.4.4  The `exit` function** of [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **Description**
>
> The `exit` function causes normal program termination to occur.  No
>   functions registered by  the `at_quick_exit` function  are  called.  If  a  program  calls  the `exit` function more than once, or calls
>   the `quick_exit` function in addition to the `exit` function, the
>   behavior is undefined.
>
> First, all functions registered by the `atexit` function are called,
>   in the reverse order of their  registration, except  that  a  function
>   is  called  after  any  previously  registered functions that had
>   already been called at the time it was registered.  If, during the
>   call to any such function, a call to the `longjmp` function is made
>   that would terminate the call to the registered function, the behavior
>   is undefined.
>
> Next,  all  open  streams  with  unwritten  buffered  data  are 
>   flushed,  all  open  streams  are closed, and all files created by the
>   `tmpfile` function are removed.
>
> Finally, control  is  returned  to  the  host  environment.   If the 
>   value  of `status` is  zero  or `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an
>   implementation-defined form of the status
>   *successful termination* is returned.  If the value of `status` is `EXIT_FAILURE`, an implementation-defined form of  the  status
>   *unsuccessful  termination* is  returned.   Otherwise  the  status  returned  is implementation-defined.

For any process that's not running under a standards-compliant C runtime, what happens upon process termination would be implementation-defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is highly system specific. First of all, these terms have multiple meanings. Let's take the specific examples of eunuchs-variants.  There, each process is a copy of parent process. It is normal for shells to set up file numbers 0, 1, and 2 set up for the child process when it runs.

These "files" are referred to as stdin, stdout, and stderr.

C programers have two layers of libraries. In eunuchs variants, you can access the system services like read or write that operate on a file idea. In addition, the standard C library has function layered upon these (e.g. fread and fwrite) that do buffer. It also defines symbols stdin, stout, and stderr which that reference structures the serve as arguments for the f_____ file function. Somewhere, embedded in these structures is the file number.

So, just in eunuchs-land, your question has two answers depending if you are referring to stdio et al. as file numbers or as symbols created by the c library?

If you are referring to the library symbols, the library has to be set up to handle program exit to flush the buffer.

If you are referring to the file numbers, that has to be handled by the operating system.

Comment: The use of 'eunuchs' in this context is not appropriate in an answer on SO.  Please edit your answer.